# How can I rename a file given a Path once the path has been moved?

Tags: rust

I am trying to rename a file named `settings.ron` -> `setting.invalid.ron`, given the path to `settings.ron` which might change depending on the environment.

I am running into trouble with moving the value of `path` when it was already borrowed in the `File` reading operation.

```rust
impl Settings {
    pub fn load() -> Self {
        let path = Settings::get_settings_path();
        if let Ok(file) = fs::File::open(path) {
            match ron::de::from_reader(file) {
                Ok(x) => x,
                Err(e) => {
                    log::warn!("Failed to parse setting file! Fallback to default. {}", e);
                    path.with_file_name("settings.invalid.ron");
                }
            }
        }
        let default_settings = Self::default();
        default_settings.save_to_file_warn();
        default_settings
    }
}
```

I got it working, but it seems odd to have to create an extra variable:

```rust
impl Settings {
    pub fn load() -> Self {
        let path = Settings::get_settings_path();
        let mut path_buf = path.to_owned();
        if let Ok(file) = fs::File::open(path) {
            match ron::de::from_reader(file) {
                Ok(x) => x,
                Err(e) => {
                    log::warn!("Failed to parse setting file! Fallback to default. {}", e);
                    path_buf.set_file_name("settings.invalid.ron");
                }
            }
        }
        let default_settings = Self::default();
        default_settings.save_to_file_warn();
        default_settings
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass `&path` to `File::open()` to avoid moving `path`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important.

Answer (score 0):

As [Sven Marnach said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406458/rename-file-given-a-path#comment101293922_57406458), the trick was to pass a reference to `File::open()`:

```rust
impl Settings {
        pub fn load() -> Self {
        let mut path = Settings::get_settings_path();
        if let Ok(file) = fs::File::open(&path) {
            match ron::de::from_reader(file) {
                Ok(x) => x,
                Err(e) => {
                    log::warn!("Failed to parse setting file! Fallback to default. {}", e);
                    // Rename the corrupted settings file
                    let mut new_path = path.to_owned();
                    new_path.pop();
                    new_path.push("settings.invalid.ron");
                    if let Err(err) = std::fs::rename(path, new_path) {
                        log::warn!("Failed to rename settings file. {}", err);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        let default_settings = Self::default();
        default_settings.save_to_file_warn();
        default_settings
    }
}
```